# how to fill chart bars width dynamically in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS so I think I'm missing something,
I need to fill charts upon the percentage of variable `lista`,
I want the value to be in the width of the `div` (line 70 in code of component).
That what I'm trying to do (dynamically)

[image]

I've edit the Picture With Inspector.
this is My component

```
import 'd3-transition';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Logo from '../../sources/Logo';
import './Articles.css';
//import Chart from './Chart';
// Tooltip
import { Tooltip } from 'react-tippy';

class Article extends Component {
    render() {
        const article = this.props.article;
        const words = this.props.words;

        const maxOccurence = Math.max(
            ...words.map((i) => article.contentWords[i]).filter((i) => i)
        );
        let lista = [...words.map((i) => article.contentWords[i]).filter((i) => i)];

        lista = lista.map(function (i) {
            return i === maxOccurence ? '100' : ((i / maxOccurence) * 100).toString();
        });

        let str = article.title;
        str = str.substring(0, 50);
        if (!maxOccurence) {
            debugger;
        }
        //--------------

        return (
            <tr className="grow">
                <td>
                    <Logo source={article.source} />
                </td>
                <td className="category">{article.category.toUpperCase()}</td>
                <td className="title grow">
                    <a
                        href={`${article.link}`}
                        rel="noopener noreferrer"
                        target="_blank"
                        style={{
                            height: 100,
                            width: '130%',
                            maxWidth: '150%',
                            minWidth: '100%',
                        }}
                    >
                        <Tooltip title={article.title} arrow={true} disabled={true}>
                            {str + '[...]'}
                        </Tooltip>
                        {/*<div>
                            <div>{str + '[...]'}</div>
                        </div>*/}
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {words.map((item) =>
                        article.contentWords[item] ? (
                            <div className="horizontal rounded">
                                <div className="progress-bar horizontal">
                                    <div className="progress-track">
                                        {/*<Chart
                                            width={lista}
                                            item={item}
                                            article={article.contentWords[item]}
                                        />*/}
                                        <div
                                            className="progress-fill "
                                            style={{
                                                width: lista[0] + '%',
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            <span>{item + ':' + article.contentWords[item]}</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ) : (
                            <></>
                        )
                    )}
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}

export default Article;
```

The `Lista` variable returns an array like this.
[image]

I hope what I explained is clear.
if I missed somthing just ask and i'll provide it :)

Comment: If you inspect the element in the DOM, what is the `width` style set to? It looks like you're always referencing `lista[0]`; did you mean to use different indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `words` and `lista` have the same length and the `lista` is based on `words` so you could use the `index` of  `{words.map((item,index) =>` in

```
style={{ width: lista[index] + '%', }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but can you please explain more?

Comment: i think that you want to use the percentage in lista to define the width of progress fill, so you should iterate over words using map function that gives you `item` and `index` then use that index to reference the percentage width in the `lista` array